# Fish shell: How to disable help message?

Tags: configuration, fish

When I start fish, it prints:

```
Welcome to fish, the friendly interactive shell
Type `help` for instructions on how to use fish
```

And then the prompt.

I've actually used fish for a while so I don't need this welcome message. How can I disable it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13995857/suppress-or-customize-intro-message-in-fish-shell) but tldr youll want to use the command `set -U fish_greeting ""`

you can customise the welcome prompt too by typing what you want in the double quotes e.g `set -U fish_greeting ""`

Comment: Ah, I searched in Unix but not on SO - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

(From https://fishshell.com/docs/current/faq.html#how-do-i-change-the-greeting-message)

Change the value of the variable **fish_greeting** or create a fish_greeting function. For example, to remove the greeting use:

```
set -U fish_greeting
```

Or if you prefer not to use a universal variable, use:

```
set -g fish_greeting
```

in **config.fish** (*this is what worked on my system*).